# Does Microsoft support Exchange 2010 on Server 2008 R2 with Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010

Will Microsoft provide support for Exchange 2010 installed on Server 2008 R2 with Active Directory? I know they advise against this. They have for the past four Exchange versions. The concern is will they provide support?

Comment: I take it you mean both roles on the same server?

Answer (score 3):

It is supported, but not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much what is done with SBS (exactly what is going to be done with SBS7). It's a compromise in security, performance, and stability. That being said, it is a supported configuration.